# Const reference as class member

Tags: c++, class, reference, constants, member

Even if the subject was discussed many times around here, I can't find a conclusive explanation regarding my particular case. Will `const` extend the lifetime of the `RefTest` temporary? Is the below example legal?

```
#include <iostream>

class RefTest
{
public:
    RefTest(const std::string &input) : str(input) {}
    ~RefTest () {std::cout << "RefTest" << std::endl;}
private:
    std::string str;
};

class Child
{
public:
    Child (const RefTest &ref) : ref_m(ref) {}
    ~Child () {std::cout << "Test" << std::endl;}
private:
    const RefTest &ref_m;
};

class Test
{
public:
    Test () : child(RefTest("child")) {}//Will the temporary get destroyed here?
    ~Test () {std::cout << "Test" << std::endl;}
private:
    const Child child;
};

int main ()
{
   Test test;
}
```

Comment: That last line isn't creating an object at all.  It's declaring a function.  See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_vexing_parse.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth Oh, shoot. I was afraid the example is stupid :( Please see my updated one, which should be a bit closer to my real-life situation. This time, I don't think there should be any vexing parse issues.

Comment: @NayanaAdassuriya which `test2`? I had rewrite my initial example, because I didn't put enough thought in it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Does a const reference prolong the life of a temporary?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2784262/does-a-const-reference-prolong-the-life-of-a-temporary)

Comment: @carleeto Yes, Haroogan already linked it. Thanks.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The reference does *not* extend the lifetime. The code is legal, but only because you never access `ref_m` after the constructor finishes.

The temporary is bound to the constructor parameter, `ref`. Binding another reference to it later, `ref_m`, doesn't extend the lifetime. If it did, you'd have an object on the stack which has to persist as long as the reference member it's bound to, which could be allocated on the heap, so the compiler would be unable to unwind the stack when the constructor returns.

It would be nice to get a warning, but compilers aren't perfect and some things are difficult to warn about. The temporary is created in a different context from where it's bound to a reference, so the compiler can only tell there's a problem with inlinging turned on, or some clever static analysis.

Comment: Oh, bloody hell. It didn't occur to me that it will bind to the function parameter, rather than the internal member. Thank you for pointing that out.

Comment: Even if you create a temporary in the child constructor e.g. `ref_m(RefTest(""))` then it won't extend the lifetime past the end of the constructor, for the same reason that the temporary is in the constructor's stack frame and has to be destroyed when that function returns. The standard explicitly says:  "A temporary bound to a reference member in a constructor’s ctor-initializer (12.6.2) persists until the constructor exits." 12.2 [class.temporary]

Comment: Indeed. Then most of the answers I've seen here related to my question are misleading. I was under the impression that if I assign a temporary to a **const** reference, then the object will be destroyed only after the reference goes out of scope, and not the temporary itself.

Answer (score 10):

The **C++ standard** states:

> The second context is when a reference is bound to a temporary. The
>   temporary to which the reference is bound or the temporary that is the
>   complete object to a subobject of which the temporary is bound
>   persists for the lifetime of the reference except as specified below.
>   **A temporary bound to a reference member in a constructor’s
>   ctor-initializer (12.6.2) persists until the constructor exits.** A
>   temporary bound to a reference parameter in a function call (5.2.2)
>   persists until the completion of the full expression containing the
>   call.

**NOTE**: And by the way, this is duplicate ([1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2784262/does-a-const-reference-prolong-the-life-of-a-temporary), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2604206/c-constant-reference-lifetime)), you should search better, next time... :)

Comment: Yes, now it's clear. Thank you for the quote from the standard.

Comment: Thanks for the references in the edit. There are too many questions around here on this subject and now I can understand why... Most of them gave me the impression that assigning a temporary to a const reference will prolong its life until the reference goes out of scope.